# Replacement of BsonBaseSerializer in MongoDB driver v2.4.0

Tags: mongodb

We have migrated MongoDB drivers from v1.9.3 to v2.4.0. we have used `BsonBaseSerializer`, which does not exists in v2.4.0. what is the replacement of `BsonBaseSerializer` in v2.4.0?

Comment: Programming language?

Answer (score 3):

There's not really enough of a question to give a full answer to, but the change you're looking for is documented under serialization in the mongo docs.

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/bson/serialization/#implementation-1

The biggest change being that they take a type now on the base class.

So

*V1 Driver code*

```
public class IntegerCoercion : BsonBaseSerializer
{
    public override object Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {
        if (bsonReader.CurrentBsonType == BsonType.Int32)
        {
            return bsonReader.ReadInt32();
        }
        if (bsonReader.CurrentBsonType == BsonType.String)
        {
            var value = bsonReader.ReadString();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }
        bsonReader.SkipValue();
        return null;
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            bsonWriter.WriteNull();
            return;
        }
        bsonWriter.WriteInt32(Convert.ToInt32(value));
    }
}
```

*V2 Driver Code*

```
public class IntegerCoercion : SerializerBase<object>
{
    public override object Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        if (context.Reader.CurrentBsonType == BsonType.Int32)
        {
            return context.Reader.ReadInt32();
        }
        if (context.Reader.CurrentBsonType == BsonType.String)
        {
            var value = context.Reader.ReadString();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }
        context.Reader.SkipValue();
        return null;
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            context.Writer.WriteNull();
            return;
        }
        context.Writer.WriteInt32(Convert.ToInt32(value));
    }
}
```

Not a huge difference but as with most of the driver changes they're minimal but breaking.